# Prompting to make a selection in a Photoshop action

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

A little help with creating an action. I'm trying to crop a bunch of photos and apply some filters to them. The problem is I want to crop each photo differently. Is it possible to stop the action and let user to make a selection and continue playing action automatically?

Comment: No. You'd need to write a script utilizing the scriptUI for that functionality.

Comment: You realize you are defeating the purpose of the script to automate your workflow.  Why not manually adjust what you need and script the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I don't think it is possible** to script a prompt for a selection since the action recorded uses precise dimensions. If you record a selection of 400 x 600, that is what it will use each time.

**But what you CAN do is**

1. Create 2 separate actions for before and after your selection.
2. Assign a shortcut key (Function like F1) to those actions.
3. Now, hit the shortcut for the first action, make your selection, then hit the second action.

This should speed up your workflow.